# The projection $\mathbb{A}^n\ni V(I)\to \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ is closed

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

During a lecture in algebraic geometry the following fact was mentioned without proof

> If we consider an affine variety $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and the map $f_n:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$ $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1})$ then if $(0:0:\dots:1)$ is not in the projective closure of X then $f(X)$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$.

The only suggestion was to look at the (to be proven to be) commutative diagram (where $\varphi_n(x_1,\dots x_n)=(1:x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and $\overline{f_n}(x_0:\dots:x_n)=(x_0:\dots :x_{n-1}$))

$$ \begin{matrix} 
X& \rightarrow_{\varphi_n}& \overline{X}\\
\downarrow_{f_n} & &  \downarrow_{\overline{f}_n}\\
\mathbb{A}^{n-1} &\rightarrow_{\varphi_{n-1}}& \mathbb{P}^{n-1}
\end{matrix}$$

However I don't see how this makes thing easier, it looks to me that removing the last coordinate from an affine variety is as hard as doing it from a projective one (id est quite hard given that all my attempts failed), on the other hand proving this is a commutative diagram is quite easy.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: $\overline{f}_n$ is proper hence universally closed.

Comment: The Zarinski topology is not Haussdorf so I'm not sure if we can say that proper implies universally closed.
Moreover even if that map was closed I think we would still need the map from X to $\overline(X)$ to be closed and I don't think it is

Comment: The definition of a proper morphism is a morphism which is separated, finite type and universally closed so yes, $\overline{f}_n$ is universally closed. Now $f_n$, as a pull-back of $\overline{f}_n$ is also closed. You don't need to say anything about $\varphi_n$ (which indeed isn't closed).

Comment: @Roland Nice, what if I wasn't allowed to use the definition of proper morphism? (the curse is an introductury curse in the topic). Also why is it the pull-back? Shoudn't a pull back have the same codomain of the function you are pulling back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like a homework or an exercise you have to solve, so I don't think is very usueful to spoon feed you the solution.

What I can suggest is to focus on the relationship between the two vertical functions and aftert you got that look at what does $\overline{f}_n$ to closed sets.